# Как удалить содержимое <!-- <> --> HTML через JS

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый вечер, как можно заменить содержимое block92

```
<!-- <block92> -->
<tr>
  <div>
  </div>
</tr>
<!-- </block92> -->
```

делать замену через JS, чтоб получилось:

```
<!-- <block92> -->
    <salam>
    </salam>
<!-- </block92> -->
```

Comment: А перед `<!-- <block92> -->` что находится?

Comment: @RomanGrinyov <td valign="top"> и т.д., примерно 500 строк кода.

Comment: @developer,  div в tr, обёрнутый  td, очень странный код

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос (кнопка `Править`): дайте больше кода. Именно интересует родители `<!-- <block92> -->` и то что перед ним. В общем, чтобы было видно дерево DOM.

Comment: Ищи ноду комментария (Node.nodeType === 8) в предке и там уже ищи нужный комментарий.

Comment: дерьмовый подход, смотрите на подобное http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027830/is-it-possible-to-get-reference-to-comment-element-block-by-javascript разбираете ноды из которых состоит документ, если ваш коммент, считываем контент до окончания коммента, удалем его, вставляем, все что пожелаете. [Версия 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623734/selecting-html-comments-with-jquery)

Comment: еще пример https://jsfiddle.net/tovic/DdpRg/

Comment: Хорошо, всем спасибо за ответы. :)

Comment: Кстати, а зачем вам это понадобилось: интересно применение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Было самому интересно реализовать и вспомнить JavaScript заодно, поэтому написал следующую функцию, обозвав её как `insertNodeIntoCommentBlock()`. Эта функция вырезает всё, что находится после открывающего тега-комментария (первый аргумент: `commentBlock`) и до закрывающего тега-комментария, заменяя вырезанный контент на переданный узел (второй аргумент: `node`), если он был передан (то есть второй аргумент необязателен):

```
<!-- <tag> -->
всё, что находится здесь, будет вырезано;
а если был передан узел вторым аргументом,
то он будет вставлен вместо уничтоженного контента
<!-- </tag> -->
обратите внимание, что последний тег-комментарий — закрывающий,
то есть со слешем: </...>
```

Основная проблема заключается в выборке открывающего тега-комментария без перебора всего дерева DOM.

...

Так как вы не предоставили полного дерева, то я оттолкнулся от `document.body`.

Результат можно посмотреть через инспектор кода.

> Я немного изменил вёрстку, чтобы показать, что вырезается всё внутри, включая комментарии и следующие за ними узлы.

```js
var commentBlock = document.body.firstChild.nextSibling;
var node = document.createElement('salam');


insertNodeIntoCommentBlock( commentBlock, node );


function insertNodeIntoCommentBlock( commentBlock, node ) {

  while ( commentBlock.nextSibling ) {

    if (

      commentBlock.nextSibling.nodeType === 8
      &&
      commentBlock.nextSibling.data.replace('/', '') === commentBlock.data

    ) {

      break;

    }

    commentBlock.nextSibling.parentNode.removeChild( commentBlock.nextSibling );

  }
  
  
  if ( node ) {

    commentBlock.nextSibling.parentNode.insertBefore( node, commentBlock.nextSibling );

  }


};
```

```html
<!-- <block92> -->
<tr>
  <div>
  </div>
</tr>
<!-- </block> -->
<blablabla></blablabla>
<!-- </block92> -->
blablabla
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ye8ger4/